# Angular-UI tooltip messes with keypress event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I 'm using the following directive to listen to enter keypresses on an input element:

```
.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
})
```

This works as expected. When I add a tooltip directive on the input element the above directive no longer works. Is there a workaround for this?

UPDATE

After  bingjie2680's suggestion I tried to use ng-keypress and ng-keydown but stumbled upon another problem. The above directives seem to affect the ng-model directive of the same element. The model becomes undefined. Here is the input tag:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="tags" 
       tooltip="tooltip text here"
       tooltip-placeent="top"
       tooltip-trigger="focus"
       ng-model="currentTag" ng-keydown="addTag($event)" />
```

And here is the relevant part of addTag:

```
    $scope.addTag = function($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode !== 13) return;

        console.log($scope.currentTag);     <-- currentTag is undefined here
        ...
    }
```

Why is the model getting undefined? Everything works fine if I don't include the tooltip directive.

Comment: Why do you need tooltip directive? Bootstrap has `tooltip` attribute

Comment: Well, I don't, but I rely on ui.bootstrap for other directives and ui.bootstrap is compatible with bootstrap 2.3.2. I can only find tooltip component in the newest (3.0.0) version.

Comment: angular has ng-keypress directive, you could use that and put your logic in controller.

Comment: See the updated post. ng-keypress works but the addTag in the template must be changed to addTag($event, currentTag) to save the value of currentTag in the function's scope. Is this normal or am I missing something? Shouldn't currentTag also be accessible as $scope.currentTag from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

To make this more specific to the real issue at hand I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078580/ui-bootstrap-tooltip-and-ng-model-in-input-element-dont-play-well-together). It was 'the dot' scoping issue. More about this [here](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)