# ui.bootstrap tooltip and ng-model in input element don't play well together?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create an input element with a tooltip and bind a function to the enter keypress event. Each of these functionalities work in itself, but not combined. Here is the markup:

```
  <input type="text"
    tooltip="tooltip text" 
    tooltip-placement="top"
    tooltip-trigger="mouseover"
    ng-model="currentTag" 
    ng-keypress="addTag($event)" />
```

and the controller relevant piece:

```
  $scope.addTag = function($event) {
    if($event.keyCode !== 13) return;

    console.log($scope.currentTag);     <---- currentTag is undefined here.
    ...
  };
```

If I omit the tooltip directives the code works fine. What happens to the $scope that makes currentTag undefined? How can I fix this so that the above works?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have:

ng-model="**$parent**.currentTag"

---

The angular-ui boostrap FAQ addresses this specific problem in the section ["My input elements stop working when I place a tooltip / popover on it"](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#my-input-elements-stop-working-when-i-place-a-tooltip--popover-on-it).

Presumably referring to [scope behavior in angular < 1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945278/135114), the FAQ states *(emphasis added)*:

> This is a scoping issue. In the current version of AngularJS each DOM element can have one and only one scope.
>   [...]
>   Currently the best option of working around this problem is to prefix an expression inside the ngModel with a **parent** scope

You can't fix it just by following the [best practice guideline to "always have a '.' in your ng-models"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes); you need to work around the angular scoping limitation by actually binding to a value in the **parent**.

And don't worry, **the current scope will also get the same value through inheritance from the parent**. So after binding to `$parent.currentTag`, you'll be able to refer to it as `$scope.currentTag`

Answer (score 0):

After going back to RTFM about angular scopes I stumbled upon this [video](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) which gave me the answer.

In short, the above template ng-model should be

`ng-model="whateverYourCurrentModelIs.currentTag"`

and should be accessed accordingly in the controller.