# AngularJS Scope differences between 1.0.x and 1.2.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As of the release of the next stable AngularJS, I am migrating my application from version **1.0.8** to **1.2**.

In AngularJS **1.0.8** it was possible to set up an isolated scope for directives like `follow`. The directive would then use its own `test()` function instead of the controller's `test()` function.

## HTML

```
<my-dialog property="something">
    <button ng-click="test()">Load Test</button>
    Check out the test: "{{ testMessage }}"
</my-dialog>
```

## Javascript

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function(scope) {
    scope.test = function () {
       scope.testMessage = 'CTRL Test loaded! Whooops.';
    }
  })

  .directive('myDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          property: '='
      },
      link: function(scope) {
          scope.test = function () {
            scope.testMessage = 'Isolated Test loaded. Yes!';
          }
      }
    };
```

In AngularJS **1.2** this behavior doesn't work anymore. Clicking the button fires the controller's `test()` function now.

See this jsFiddle comparison:

- [Angular 1.0.8](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Lp2/)
- [Angular 1.2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/eM88p/)

What exactly has changes and how can I reproduce the old behavior?

### Note

I figured out I could place the directives template inside an extra HTML file or compile it as a string to get it working ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rug3J/)) but it seems to be too much in my case, as the template is fixed and splitting the HTML over several partial HTML files is a hassle.

### EDIT

[@elclanr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19944053/981933) works fine when there are no other properties to share. I updated [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rug3J/2/) to pass some arbitrary property. How should I proceed now?

Comment: Just `scope: true` http://jsfiddle.net/rug3J/1/. I would also advice to follow convention and name it `scope` and not `$scope` when it's not dependency injected.

Comment: @elclanrs Oh thanks! That was easy. Could you post it as an answer and  I can mark this questions as answered.

Comment: Interesting- I just checked and this changed between rc3 and now.   Besides setting scope to true you can also use:  `scope: {test: '&'}`.  I confirmed that works as expected- passing test through into the isolate scope.

Comment: @KayakDave Thank you for the documentation this seem to make sense. `{test: '&'}` is no option for me as I don't want to use the controllers test() function.

Comment: Just to be sure it's all clear {test: '&'} will cause ng-click="test()" to call your directive's `test()` instead of the controller's.  The same behavior as setting scope to true- except you'll be using an isolate scope for everything else.

Comment: @KayakDave I've tested it and it uses the controllers test() function. (which makes sense to me as everything is isolated except the test() function) Or am I getting something wrong? :) http://jsfiddle.net/rug3J/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41071/discussion-between-flek-and-kayakdave)

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.  I messed up and ran the test on 1.0.8.  That's how it worked on the old code, but clearly I've got to wrap my head around this new approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is an intended result of the breaking change: [github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/…](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7) Which was pulled in 1.2.0 (after rc3) (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md - see the first breaking change for 1.2.0 - $compile):

> Fixes issue with isolate scope leaking all over the place into other directives on the same element.
>
> **Isolate scope is now available only to the isolate directive that requested it and its template.**
>
> A non-isolate directive should not get the isolate scope of an isolate directive on the same element,instead they will receive the original scope (which is the parent scope of the newly created isolate scope).

Also check out this discussion: [github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4889](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4889)

Notably: "The isolate scope is only applied to the template, but not to markup that was not contributed by the directive. Before 1.2 isolate scopes had a bug that caused this kind of leakage. **The point of the isolate scope is that it only applies to the directive that declared it, and not to other directives or markup.**" (from tbosch)

Previous to **1.2.0** everything on the same DOM element shared the same scope.  **So 1.2.0 makes a substantial change to how directives with isolate scopes work.**

Comment: Hey great answer, behavior makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `scope: true` should solve the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/rug3J/1. I would also advise to follow convention and name it `scope` and not `$scope` when it's not dependency injected:

```
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.test = function () {
        scope.testMessage = 'Isolated Test loaded. Yes!';
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you have an ideal why it doesn't work when I pass other properties? I updated my question and the jsFiddle accordingly.

Comment: It seems as soon as you set an isolate scope, then the controller's scope takes precedence. TBH I'm not sure what has changed since Angular 1.0.8 that breaks the previous behavior.

Comment: Post back if you find a solution, I'm curious now, haven't found anything relevant in the not so good documentation...

Comment: I can confirm that by setting the scope:true to our isolated directives, we solved our issues in the current 1.2.x migration.

Answer (score 0):

In order to combine normal markup with directive specific templates and function one need to make use of the **transclude** option like so:

See: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5pRm/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <my-directive property="{{ something }}">
            <p>{{ text }}</p>
        </my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'This is a controllers text.';
    $scope.something = 'This is another controllers text.';
}])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<button ng-click="test()">Fire directives function</button><div ng-transclude></div><p>{{ property }}</p>',
        scope: {
            property: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.test = function () {
                scope.property = 'Loaded directives text.';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This works fine for me now but it should be noted that one can not override existing properties of the scope.