# Angular isolated scope in directive refers to the parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I know there has been some changes in angular with isolated scope inside a directive. However I have not been able to figure out why I get the wrong scope on the element inside the directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.val1 = '11';
    $rootScope.val2 = '22';
})
.directive('dir1', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: '<a onclick="angular.element(this).scope().test()">template</a>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            scope.test = function(){console.log('test');}
        }
    };
});
```

Here is also [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davekr/ydJB9/2/).

On the `onclick` event, the scope refers to the `$rootScope` and not the scope of the directive. So it doesn't find the `test` method which is undefined.

What I am missing is why am I getting the wrong scope from the element inside the directive. I could do `angular.element($("a")[0]).scope().test()` and the result will be the same.

This code worked in previous versions. No idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you could look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943935/angularjs-scope-difference-1-0-x-vs-1-2-x

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your template to...

```
'<a ng-click="test()">template</a>'
```

... and it should work. Onlick is a browser function that executes global state and has nothing to do with angular and it's scope model. So stick to the angular directives like `ng-click` and use can use methods you defined on your scope.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXs3h/1/) that executes the function and has a reference to the element.

Comment: It should evaluate to the right scope though, becuase I'm passing there the element reference (`this`). Also I'm trying to upload files and there is a hidden input where I need the `onclick`. `ng-click` somehow doesn't work well.

Comment: In angular directives you get a reference to your element as argument in the link function. Thats why you have the `element` argument. Using onlick and global function within is a wrong approach in angular. Probably read some more of the docs for directives. docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Ok, I know `onclick` is not the angular way, but it's not the issue here. I can do `angular.element($("a")[0]).scope().test()` and the result will be the same, which is not the expected behaviour according to docs.

Comment: Ok, probably I got you wrong, but as far as I understood all you want is to execute `test()` by clicking on you a-element and to have a reference on you element inside the test function!?!

Comment: Perhaps I formulated my question wrong. I will edit it. Thanks for the answer.