# Accessing data outside isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have this situation where I have directive with isolated scope.From my understanding, I'm restricted to this scope inside directive, but I was wondering if there might be a way to access(change) data from the parent scopes without attribute bindings to isolate scope ? This is the code that I'm trying to edit:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tdJCtP7FJVZn28FPAuv3?p=preview

You'll see that it actually works right now with angular 1.0.8, but not with 1.2.8(as expected).I'm confused how it could work at all with 1.0.8, `scope.resizeGridColumns` is in parent scope(MyCtrl) ? So I need help to make this code work in 1.2.x(just change from 1.0.8 to 1.2.8 in script tag)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945278/1140134

Also, without attribute bindings, you can put `scope: true` which creates a new scope for the directive which prototypically inherits from the parent scope.

Comment: I actually ended up with using scope:true and made it to work that way in 1.2.x.After another glance at the code I have better understanding of what's going on but now I don't get why it fails in 1.2.x.I mean inherited scope in this directive uses 2-way bindings(=), but resizeGridColumns is actually created in inherited scope instead of updating the binding? Could you please explain that ?

Comment: Can you post a plunker with the issue? I am not getting your question.

Comment: I am referring to my first question where you replied with the link.Explanation there says nothing about property bindings in directive and that's actually here the case.The binding don't get updated in 1.2.x.In inherited scope there is a binding, resizeGridColumns: '=', and then in code scope.resizeGridColumns = scope.resizeGridColumnsSet.allColumns.So, instead of updating the binding, scope.resizeGridColumns actually creates new property on the scope.