# Angular 1.0.1 vs 1.3.0 for directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I build a simple directive with isolated scope.But it working fine with Version 1.0.1 but not in 1.3.0.What is the problem suppose to be ?

Angular 1.0.1 Version example : http://jsfiddle.net/k2rnavrg/

Angular 1.3.0 Version example :http://jsfiddle.net/k2rnavrg/2/

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('qImg', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

            m: '=mF'

        }


    };
})
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'Hello Samitha!';

}]);
```

Comment: Not that it changes your question, but you are linking to version 1.2.0 not 1.3.0

Comment: same problem in version 1.2.0

Comment: what's not working? Your problem description shouldn't require people to test 2 different versions to see how they work and figure out what behavior to expect

Comment: Have a look at the first answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943935/angularjs-scope-difference-1-0-x-vs-1-2-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not confuse directives with elements.

```
<q-img m-f="foo">
```

This is a `q-img` element that also has a `qImg` directive attached to it. The isolate scope created by this directive is only accessible to that directive, not to others, like the `ngModel` directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{foo}}
  <q-img m-f="foo">
      <input type='text' ng-model="m">
  </q-img>
```

`ng-Controller` creates a scope that is used by **all** directives seen here, except for the `qImg`directive, that uses an isolate scope.

If you want the `ngModel` directive to access the isolate scope then you would need to put the `input` into a template, not directly into the DOM:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('qImg', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="m">',
    scope: {
        m: '=mF'
    }
  };
})

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{foo}}
  <q-img m-f="foo"></q-img>
</div>
```

It seems that the behavior has changed with 1.2.