# Simple isolate scope in directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble with a simple isolated scope, using Angular 1.2.24 (latest stable version).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope) {
         scope.name = 'This is my directive';   
    }
};
```

});

```
<div my-directive>{{ name }}</div>
```

But `name` is empty. If I remove the `scope: {}` it works. Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/98f97cyt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular 1.0.1 vs 1.3.0 for directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813595/angular-1-0-1-vs-1-3-0-for-directives)

Comment: Because the scope is isolated. It cannot be accessed outside of the directive.

Comment: I'm interested in why is this behaviour in Angular 1.2 and 1.3. Can someone point me to the break change note or something similar?

Comment: Have you used Angular < 1.2 before? The old behavior wasn't ok, because it defeated the purpose of an isolated scope. [Here's the commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943935/angularjs-scope-difference-1-0-x-vs-1-2-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer: [AngularJS Scope differences between 1.0.x and 1.2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943935/angularjs-scope-difference-1-0-x-vs-1-2-x)

This behaviour is a intended breaking change, that was introduced in Angular 1.2.0 (after rc3).

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyModule">

    <div my-directive>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},      
        template:'<div>{{ name }}</div>',
        link: function(scope) {
             scope.name = 'This is my directive';   
        }
    };
});
```